# A spontaneous exergonic reaction produces a reduced entropy structure and therefore constitutes a local entropy dip?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

Total entropy of the isolated system increases due to release of work/energy, but locally, given that implicated elements are now bound together, entropy is reduced?

We can assume low temperature and constant pressure to enable the reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A good example is [crystallization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallization) in a closed system. The created crystal has lower entropy than the one its components while in the liquid. The total entropy increases due to the release of heat during the creation of the crystal.

> The crystallization process appears to violate the second principle of thermodynamics.

...

> [The second law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) states that the total entropy of an isolated system can never decrease over time, and is constant if and only if all processes are reversible. Isolated systems spontaneously evolve towards thermodynamic equilibrium, the state with maximum entropy.

...

> Whereas most processes that yield more orderly results are achieved by applying heat, crystals usually form at lower temperatures—especially by supercooling. However, due to the release of the heat of fusion during crystallization, the [entropy of the universe increases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallization#Thermodynamic_view), thus this principle remains unaltered.